# What is the difference between disséminé et éparpillé?

Tags: vocabulaire

I saw these two words in my vocabulary book but I don't know how to translate and distinguish them. The book is a Fle vocabulary book and entirely written in french so there are no translations.

I tried to translate them myself but I can't see the difference between these two words. In German they can be both translated with ausstreuen, zerstreuen and in English with to scatter and to spread out. Is there a difference in how you use them?

There are the following examples with the two words:

Malheureusement, les tableaux sont éparpillés dans le monde entier.

Les informations sont disséminées dans les archives.

Au moment de Pâques on disséminé/éparpillé des œufs en chocolat dans les jardins.

Comment: On peut ajouter _dispersé_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two words are **very** close. I can find examples were one is much more used than the other (like [*disséminer* with *indices*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indices+diss%C3%A9min%C3%A9s%2Cindices+%C3%A9parpill%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindices%20diss%C3%A9min%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindices%20%C3%A9parpill%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0)), but it's hard to find some kind of "rule of thumb" as to which one to choose.

To me, *éparpiller* is more associated with a messy, involuntary scatter, while *disséminer* can be more voluntary, like carefully hiding clues here and there, for example.

*Éparpiller* is also *slightly* negative, like it's not the goal, the "things" were supposed to stay grouped. Whereas *disséminer* fits more when it's a "good thing" that the things are spread everywhere. It's in accordance with the voluntary vs involuntary thing.

It's not a strong "rule" though, take it with a grain of salt. But it fits in most examples.